# VBA Macro Run Time Error 13 - Type Mismatch

Tags: vba

This is a string of code for a commission's report. It runs fine with zero problems daily, and was last run on the 13th.

This morning I am receiving a `Run Time Error 13 Type Mismatch`.

I have no clue why, but when I Debug, it highlights this section:

`If UCase(Cells(i, 1).Value = "200265 - MP"` Then

I have tried to retype it, but when I do, I get an error for the word Then that states the following:
`Compile error: Expected: list seperator or )`

How can I run this?

Here's the code:

```
Sheets("Errors").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
Sheets("Errors").Select
With Sheets("Errors")
    lastrow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
For i = lastrow To 1 Step -1
    Cells(i, 1).Select
    If UCase(Cells(i, 1).Value = "200265 - MP" Then
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Sheets("Temp").Select
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Sheets("Errors").Select
    End If
    If UCase(Cells(i, 1).Value) = "160850 - TP" Then
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Sheets("Temp").Select
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Sheets("Errors").Select
    End If
    If UCase(Cells(i, 1).Value) = "170566 - VB" Then
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Sheets("Temp").Select
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Sheets("Errors").Select
    End If
    If UCase(Cells(i, 1).Value) = "201447 - JB" Then
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Sheets("Temp").Select
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Sheets("Errors").Select
    End If
    If UCase(Cells(i, 1).Value) = "202006 - BL" Then
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Sheets("Temp").Select
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Sheets("Errors").Select
    End If
    If UCase(Cells(i, 1).Value) = "203646 - MM" Then
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Sheets("Temp").Select
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Sheets("Errors").Select
    End If
    If UCase(Cells(i, 1).Value) = "203917 - KT" Then
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Sheets("Temp").Select
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Sheets("Errors").Select
    End If
```

Comment: Nathan, what was edited?

Comment: You can click on the "edited x mins ago" link to see the details of an edit.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!   Any clue about the 2nd part of my question? Was actually the first part, the Run Time error 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close the bracket: write `UCase(Cells(i, 1).Value) = "200265 - MP" Then`

Edit:

It's difficult, from the comments to see what is going on. Give this a go:
Paste this function into your module

```
Public Function myUCase(ByVal v As Variant) As String
    On Error GoTo error:

    myUCase = UCase(CStr(v))
    Exit Function

error:
    myUCase = ""

End Function
```

Then replace your calls to UCase with calls to myUCase.

What I'm doing here is throwing away any error.

Use it with a degree of caution though!

Comment: So, I just reran the Macro and am still getting the Run Time Error 13 Type mismatch. Any clue why??  
I can confirm that the values of 200265 are listed in the data and that there are no alpha charachters in that column, only numeric data. Also, that there are no DIV/0 or #NA values.

Comment: I just reran the Macro and am still getting the Run Time Error 13 Type mismatch. Any clue why?? I can confirm that the values of 200265 are listed in the data and that there are no alpha charachters in that column, only numeric data. Also, that there are no DIV/0 or #NA values.

Comment: It's difficult to tell without access to the spreadsheet. Do you know what the value of i is when it crashes? If you can figure that out then you could put an if "i = <value> then Stop" just above the line. Then type debug.print Cells(i, 1).Value in the immediate window to see what is going on.

Comment: Trying to figure out what i equals. I think it's the date of the order for this commission's report? I honestly don't know and am baffled since nothing changed to the data fed into this report, or to the report/macro itself and no one else has been in it.

Comment: Wish so much that I could just send this data over to someone. I have been trying to figure this all out for over 2 hours.

Comment: Go and get a cup of tea, then when you're back, rerun it and when you get to the error, type "debug.print i" in the immediate window.

Comment: I also don't understand why it would say Rows i or Rows(i), when i is a Column, not a Row...

Comment: When I add:  "debug.print i"   into that section of the macro (no window poped up other than the run time error window), then I get the following error message:   Compile error: Expected: line number or label or statement or end of statement

Comment: I've amended my answer with a 'clobber-all' type solution

Comment: Thank you so much, but I can't throw away the error. We move them to another tab, so that our order processor will know to correct them and then they will fall away once the process has been run again. I am literally about to cry, my boss is going to flip if I don't get this out soon... :-( By the way, thank you so very very much for your help so far!!!

Comment: Try it anyway. I'm not throwing away a 'normal' error, just one that seems to be causing UCase to fail for some reason. No harm in trying ;-(

Comment: Just wanted to extend a huge bit of gratitude for your assistance this morning. Not sure what I would've done without your help! This is an amazing forum and I will be back! Thank you so very much again!!!

Comment: No problem. There are some smart folk on this site who clearly love to do a bit of problem solving from time to time. In the long term though, it would be an idea for you to go through that macro carefully when you're not under so much pressure.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a bracket

```
If UCase(Cells(i, 1).Value = "200265 - MP" Then
```

should be

```
If UCase(Cells(i, 1).Value) = "200265 - MP" Then
```

Comment: Question... do you know why the Run Time Error 13 occurred from what you see above. Asking because it came up and I have literally changed nothing. Just thought that maybe re-typing it would work, but the run time error 13 pin pointed that string as mismatch type

Comment: So, I just reran the Macro and am still getting the Run Time Error 13 Type mismatch. Any clue why??

Comment: I can confirm that the values of 200265 are listed in the data and that there are no alpha charachters in that column, only numeric data. Also, that there are no DIV/0 or #NA values

Comment: I just reran the Macro and am still getting the Run Time Error 13 Type mismatch. Any clue why?? I can confirm that the values of 200265 are listed in the data and that there are no alpha charachters in that column, only numeric data. Also, that there are no DIV/0 or #NA values.

Comment: It stops at the same line?

Comment: Yes, at the same line. :-(

Comment: I believe the UCase function takes in almost all types since it'll just cast whatever is in Cells(i,1) to string, so I'm not sure why it would give you that error.  Could you copy paste your modified IF statement from your current file.  Also try entering debug mode when it stops and mouse over Cells(i,1).Value and what does it say?

Comment: Just wanted to extend a huge bit of gratitude for your assistance this morning. Not sure what I would've done without your help! This is an amazing forum and I will be back! Thank you so very much again!!!